# Dropbox not returning values

Tags: php, html, sql

The get data method seems to be incorrect in this program, can you see what is causing the drop down box to be populated with nothing when a user interacts with it?

Update the get_data class did work, thanks for the feedback

```
 <?php
    require("db.php");
    include("functions.php");
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
      $Date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
      $FirstName = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['FirstName']);
      $LastName = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['LastName']);
      $Rating = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Rating']);
      $Comment = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Comment']);

      $sql = "INSERT INTO guest(GuestID, FirstName, LastName, PostcodeFK, Email, Date, Rating,Comment)"
       ." VALUES ('', '$FirstName', '$LastName', '$Postcode', '$Email', '$Date', '$Rating', '$Comment')";

    if($mysqli->query($sql)==TRUE)
    {
      echo "<script>alert('Record Added.'); location.href='customers.html'</script>";
    }else{
     echo "<script>alert('Error'); location.href='#'</script>"; 
    }
    function get_data($mysqli)
    {

       $sql="SELECT `MealOption` FROM menu";
       $result=$mysqli->query($sql);
           while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
          {
            echo "<option value='". $row['MealOption'] . "'>". $row['MealOption'] ."</option>";
          }

    }
    }

    ?>
    <html>

    <body>
    <form action="" method="post">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" require/><br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="LastName" require/><br>
    Postcode: <input type="number" name="Postcode" require/><br>
    Email: <input type="email" name="Email" require/><br>
    <button class="btn" onclick="get_data(Meal);">Add</button>
    <label for="Meal">Meal:</label>
    <select name="Meal">
    <?php
     //echo get_data($mysqli);   
    ?>
    </select><br>
    Rating: <input type="number" name ="Rating" min="1" max="5" require/><br>
    Comment: <input type="text" name ="Comment"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What "doesn't work" mean? What happens when the code runs?

Comment: @Cristik there is a dropdown box and it should get populated from the get_data function thats what it looks like, everything else is fine, just the menu box
http://gyazo.com/366c81a8652e856d31bf9d4d7c407077

Comment: "paid to get it checked and he said it should work" So instead of checking it you ask other people? You got money from someone to let it check by someone else?

Comment: You mean you paid to get it checked?

Comment: Where is the Javascript that includes `function get_data(obj)`?

Comment: @Loko, no i paid someone when i could not get it working, he did no edits to it and said no reason why it should not work, im willing to offer someone a cashy to help me fix it

Comment: So he just looked at it, and didn't bother to test? By the looks of it you're trying to run a javascript function and expecting a PHP function to be run. I'm not sure why you need to run the code to grab the menu dynamically anyway but you could do it with ajax.

Answer (score 2):

Your `<button class="btn" onclick="get_data(Meal);">Add</button>` with the function `get_data(Meal)` cant call a php function.

So you have to create a javascript function `get_data()` that requests the infos via ajax for example.

You should get your money back from that guy.

Comment: The word 'scammed' comes to mind

Comment: +1 for the last sentence. Just in general, but if the guy had to check that code and had to actually say what's bad practice, tell OP what he should do different etc, he definitly does not know what he's doing and he is indeed a **scammer**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your get_data function out of if statement. Indentation could help you.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $Date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  $FirstName = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['FirstName']);
  $LastName = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['LastName']);
  $Rating = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Rating']);
  $Comment = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Comment']);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO guest(GuestID, FirstName, LastName, PostcodeFK, Email, Date, Rating,Comment)"
   ." VALUES ('', '$FirstName', '$LastName', '$Postcode', '$Email', '$Date', '$Rating', '$Comment')";

   if($mysqli->query($sql)==TRUE)
   {
       echo "<script>alert('Record Added.');location.href='customers.html'</script>";
   } else {
       echo "<script>alert('Error'); location.href='#'</script>"; 
   }
}

function get_data($mysqli)
{

   $sql="SELECT `MealOption` FROM menu";
   $result=$mysqli->query($sql);
       while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
      {
        echo "<option value='". $row['MealOption'] . "'>". $row['MealOption'] ."</option>";
      }

}
```

And for html usage you need to add php tags before using php function.

```
 <?php get_data($mysqli); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not safe against XSS attacks - this might be causing the problem, e.g. if your meal option contains an apostrophe.

Try changing this line:

```
echo "<option value='". $row['MealOption'] . "'>". $row['MealOption'] ."</option>";
```

to this line:

```
echo "<option value='". htmlspecialchars($row['MealOption'],ENT_QUOTES) . "'>". htmlspecialchars($row['MealOption']) ."</option>";
```